# Proving $T_n = 2\times 20^n + 4\times 8^n$ by mathematical induction

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

Given that $T_0 = 6$ and that $T_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation

$$T_{n+1} = 20T_n - 8^n \times 48$$

I have the equation for any term $n$ to be;

$T_n = 2\times 20^n+4⋅8^n$

I want to prove this by mathematical induction, however I am unsure as to how to get the equation for the sum of the terms.

This is following on from finding this equation [in a previous thread, here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302394/simplifying-recurrence-relation-t-n1-20t-n-48-times-8n).
I'd appreciate any help on getting started with this.

Comment: Prove what? I don't see what you are trying to prove here.

Comment: Can you show us how did you do? It doesn't seems to be harder than other induction problem .

Comment: I was needing to prove that Tn=2×20n+4⋅8n is true. SRX's answer was what I was after, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Base Case: Clearly $2\times 20^0+4⋅8^0 = 6$.

The Inductive Step: Let $n$ be an arbitrary nonnegative integer. Assume that
$$T_n = 2\times 20^n+4⋅8^n.$$

Then 
\begin{align*}
T_{n+1} & = 20\, T_n - 8^n \times 48 \\
& = 20 \bigl(2\times 20^n+4\times8^n\bigr) - 8^n \times 48 \\
& = 2\times 20^{n+1}+80\times8^n - 8^n \times 48 \\
& = 2\times 20^{n+1}+32\times8^n \\
& = 2\times 20^{n+1}+4\times8^{n+1} \\
\end{align*}
Thus
$$
T_{n+1} = 2\times 20^{n+1}+4\times8^{n+1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prove the statement by M.I., the induction step is just
\begin{align}
T_{n+1} & = 20T_n - 48 \times 8^n\\
& = 20(2 \times 20^n + 4 \times 8^n) - 48 \times 8^n\\
& = 2 \times 20^{n+1} + (80-48) \times 8^n\\
& = 2 \times 20^{n+1} + 32 \times 8^n\\
& = 2 \times 20^{n+1} + 4 \times 8^{n+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Oh cool thanks, so I didn't need the equation for the sum of the terms.

Comment: That equation from Andrews is just for you know observing the pattern, but that is essential: imagine if you cannot observe the pattern, you don't even have a "statement" to prove my M.I.

Comment: I was a bit confused as to how ∑(k=0 to n−1) 20^n−1−k 8^k got to         20^n−8^n/20−8 in Andrew's working, although I'm not sure if that warrants a separate question.